# Can't open port 19132 UDP on my Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: networking, server, minecraft, port-forwarding

I'm hosting a Minecraft Pocket: Edition server on my 16.04 Ubuntu server that I bought from OVH. I started up the server (it's hosted with pocketmine-mp a php app) and I can join it with no issues on port 19132. And everyone else can as well. But my problem is, whenever I try to register my server into a mcpe server ad sight, it's not able to find my port 19132 as open. I as well as checked with a port checking tool and it says port 19132 on my server is closed. I don't know whether it is something to do with OVH. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: "it's not able to find my port 19132 as open", but it is the server that is supposed to open the port, isn't it? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Well, the website says that port 19132 is closed on my Ubuntu Server.

Comment: First check if the port is assigned to your process by executing `netstat -tulpan`. If you can find the desired process with the expected port number, check your firewall rules.

Comment: Yes. 19132 is in the list but it's state is empty. There is no text in its state. How do I make it 'Listen'? If that'd make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you port-forwarding on your router?
If not, Find out how here: http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

If your not port forwarding then no one externally will be able to join. (not in your network)